# Timestamps for future intervals

Tags: node.js, api, date, datetime

I have to store my user's availability for example (mon-wed, 10 am to 1 pm), and then use this data to query their calendars to check if they are busy/free

So let's say today it's 29 Jan, Saturday. I want to check availability for the upcoming Tuesday. Now I'll have to generate timestamps for the upcoming Tuesday which would be `1643673600` to `1643846400`

How do I generate them? I wanted to write some logic but I have failed. I want to consider the user's timezone too. Is there any API service or package that I can use for this purpose?

Answer (score 1):

check "day.js" npm package, that should help you a lot, it has unix timestamps as well as timezones support

more info https://day.js.org/en/

Answer (score 1):

There is a package called "MomentJs".

[Here is a link to the main document page](https://momentjs.com/)

[Here is a link to the document for Unix Timestamp](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/unix-timestamp-milliseconds/)

Use this below code if it solves your problem.

```
moment().add(3, 'days').unix()
```

```js
console.log(moment().add(3, 'days').unix());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```